# If text box is empty choose option and insert to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, textbox

I am working on a recipe website one of the fields on the recipe upload page gives the user the option to either upload a value via a dropdown menu or add a new one via a text box

I have made it work so when the dropdown has no value it will choose the text however this does not work the other way round I'm getting this error:

Insert failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '30'>English

Here is the insert code:

```
if($cuisine==""){
    $query="INSERT INTO`recipename`(cuisine_type)VALUES('$cuisinetype')";
    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
    mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)) ;
}
//check whether the cuisine type exists//
if ($cuisinetype !='empty'){
    $query="SELECT cuisine_type FROM `Nation` WHERE cuisine_type='$cuisine'";
    $result=mysqli_query($db_server, $query) ;
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $message = "Sorry we already have that one!";
}else{
    $query = "INSERT INTO`Nation`(cuisine_type)VALUES('$cuisine')";
    mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
    mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is exactly the reason why your code is subject to SQL Injection.

Comment: ok but that doesnt help?

Comment: You might think it does not. You will thank me later :)

Comment: @mjayt, my comment was not only a security tip, but if you look closely, it is directly related to his problem.

Comment: You should use proper spacing for your PHP and MySQL codes, this will save you a lot of headaches in the future. I'm not sure what `if ($cuisinetype !='empty'){` is achieving. Your SQL syntax errors may also be coming from input containing quotation marks such as `'` because they are escaping your `VALUES` string (which also gives you SQL injection vulnerabilities.) You should only select your database once. I'd recommend you read up on proper examples of the usage for `mysqli_*` functions

Comment: I know @Hanlet gave a vague "hint" but I added explanation for OP's benefit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `Nation` (cuisine_type) VALUES ('$cuisine')";
```

Add spaces!

Anyway, please, take a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php) to prevent SQL Injections, just in case you've missed it.